# different stylesheet for different pages in laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm new to laravel. I have two pages A and B which uses tables. Now in my layout.blade.php I have a link towards only one stylesheet which is affecting both the tables in A and B. I only want it in A and for B I have different set of stylesheet. How do I target the stylesheet to the pages?

Comment: You can include them on `blade` or set a variable for to identify the page and `link` the stylesheet accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can load css files directly in these views, so A would load one css and B will load another one.

Another way if to use conditional loading in `layout.blade.php`:

```
@if (request()->is('pageA'))
    // Load CSS for A
@elseif (request()->is('pageB'))
    // Load CSS for B
@endif
```

Comment: @extends('layout')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/Astyle.css">
@section('content')

and for b page
@extends('layout')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/Bstyle.css">
@section('content')

Answer (score 2):

Usually in this case you should have a master layout that only include global scripts and stylesheets, says `layouts/global.blade.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Your website</title>

    @section('meta')
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    @show

    @section('stylesheets')
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{asset("favicon.ico")}}" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset("css/global.css")}}"/>
    @show

    @section('scripts')
        <script src="{{url("js/global.js")}}"></script>
    @show
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your `page_a.blade.php`, you extend it and include your own specific stylesheets:

```
@extends('layouts/global')

@section('stylesheets')
    @parent
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{url("css/page_a.css")}}"/>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    @parent
    <script src="{{url("js/page_a.js")}}"></script>
@endsection

@section('content')
    Your page A content
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may create a section like the following in your view, for example:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('styles')
   <link href="{{asset('assets/css/custom-style.css')}}" />
@stop
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sass css for that conditions. In that sass css you can use if and else condition and check  variable.
Please refer below link for how to use it.

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while